# How do I find all elements that have a title attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I find all elements that have a title attribute using jQuery? It's for enabling tooltips using the tipsy jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('[title]')
```

This will do the job.

Comment: Note that for the tipsy plugin to work, i had to make sure the title is not empty. Like this: `$('[title!=""]').tipsy();`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Has Attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector:

```
$("[title]").something();
```