# Jquery, getting image with custom attribute

Tags: jquery

Can you please give me a hint on how do I get the value of a specific image by a custom attribute .
For example, I have :

```html
<img class="image" 
     identif="<?php echo $j; ?>" 
     id="<?php echo $id; ?>" 
     src="../<?php echo $sqlg[$pic] ?>" 
     h="<?php echo $heightl; ?>" 
     w="<?php echo $widthl ?>"
     height="<?php echo $height; ?>px" 
     width="<?php echo $width; ?>px" 
     title="Double-click to enlarge image" />
```

I want in jquery to get the "src" of the image by the "identif" attribute, thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value) and [Selecting element by data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute) or maybe [How do I find all elements that have a title attribute using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186849/how-do-i-find-all-elements-that-have-a-title-attribute-using-jquery).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's better to use instead a `data-*` attribute like so

```
<img class="image" data-identif="<?php echo $j; ?>"...
```

and thus you can retrieve that attribute with

```
$('img[data-identif]').data('identif');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ for further reference

If you need to grab the src of an img with `data-identif = 5` just do like so:

```
$('img[data-identif="5"]').attr('src');
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is trying to do. It seems he wants t find the image(s) with the `identif` attribute and get its/their `src` attribute.

Comment: yeah , but I want to grab the src value from the image with the field lets say indentif is equal to 5 .

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('img[data-identif="1"]')
```